# How to preserve apt-cache archive directory when using docker / host volumes

Tags: caching, ubuntu, chef-infra, docker, apt-get

The use case is fairly straightforward.  I am dockerizing our local provisioning (which utilizes chef to configure our ubuntu servers).  I am using a few data volumes to share host directories that I want as a cache for the docker containers:
eg:

```
docker run -d -P -h docker -v /foo/apt-cache:/var/cache/apt/archives foo:base
```

However, the debian package files in /var/cache/apt/archives directory keep getting blown out after each package install.  Can someone point me to where this happens in docker and a workaround, so I can preserve my apt-get cache nicely across containers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

sharing /var/cache/apt/archives seems a fragile solution. Maybe you should give a try to setting up a container running apt-cacher-ng and configure apt on your other containers to use that proxy.

Docker has an [article](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/apt-cacher-ng/) explaining how to set this up.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the suggestion; I will check out that article.  Though for my own edification, would you happen to know why these packages would be removed?  I am utilizing other volumes for cache-related behavior that persist across builds/runs without issue, so I'm wondering if there is some apt-get clean operation that is happening under the covers. Removal of the cached deb packages def. wasn't occurring before when using vagrant + chef by themselves.

Comment: I have no idea, but having chef and vagrant provisioning does make a lot of suspects for some sort of apt actions. Maybe a dumb guess but apt might also keep track of what's in its cache with index files that may be stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Realized that I needed to remove "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache" file from the docker ubuntu base image.

There are some hooks in there to remove debian packages from the cache after install (to reduce space  taken up in containers)

Comment: you might run into some odd issues if multiple docker images are using the same mounted volume. if two docker images are spun up roughly at the same time, one container could potentially overwrite files being used by another container. the advantage of apt-cacher-ng (plus apt proxy setting) is that you safely cache packages on the LAN. are you caching for docker image creation (where parallelism isn't an issue), or are you modifying running containers as if they were lightweight VMs (with entrypoint of bash or similar)?

Comment: @ives layer caching is a fine tradeoff, but if most of your time is wasted for some reason on packages, why not bind-mount ?
- in local: it will work like Vagrant's plugin to cache package manager stuff
- in gitlab ci: it will pack/unpack the cache dirs on every build
So in my case at least, there doesn't seem to be any concrete risk, just speed boost, without having to maintain a caching proxy for apk/apt/yum/pip/npm and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, adding `RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean` before `apt xxx` in the Dockerfile fixed the issue for me